# Get first occurrence after specific row in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My questions regarding this topic are twofold (in bold):
I am using a Dataframe to manage a large amount of data in the following format:

| Time | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Start |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | R |
| 6 | A |
| 7 | Start |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | R |

The goal is to have a new column storing the time difference from the first message after a 'Start' message until the first 'R' message. This 'Start' to 'Start' pattern cycles repeats thousands of times in a dataframe. I am marking rows that contain the first after a 'Start' message using the following code:

```
df['Shift'] = df['Data'].shift()
df['first_in_cycle'] = df['Shift'].str.contains('Start')
df.drop(columns='Shift', inplace=True)
```

Then I attempt to mark the first occurrence of an 'R using the following code:

```
counter = (df['Data'].str.contains('Start')).cumsum()
first_r = df[df['Data'].str.contains('R')].groupby(counter).transform('idxmin')
df.loc[first_r.index, 'first_R'] = True
```

However, the result of this is a Dataframe with all of the 'R' messages marked as true, which is incorrect. **I am unsure of how to fix this issue.**

The plan was to get both of the flag columns correct then merge them using .any(), removing all rows that are marked as false, then using .diff() to calculate the difference between the 'R' and 'Start'. **Is this the best way to accomplish this?**

The following is the desired output given the initial example:

| Time | Data | Time Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 5 | R | 3 |
| 7 | Start |  |
| 8 | 3 |  |
| 9 | R | 1 |

Comment: Is the R message always followed by Start? I mean is there always a fixed pattern `Start -> R -> Start -> R` ?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma There will always be at least 1 R message in between Starts. There could be multiple or just one. The guarantee is at least one. We

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#create default index if necessary
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
#check Start and R
m1 = df['Data'].str.contains('Start')
m2 = df['Data'].str.contains('R')
#groups by Start
g = m1.cumsum()
#get first R per groups to mask
mask1 = m2.groupby(g).transform('idxmax').eq(df.index)
#get Start + one row after Start
mask2 = m1.groupby(g).shift(fill_value=True)
#boolean indexing
df = df[mask1 | mask2]

#get difference per groups
df['Time Difference'] = df['Time'].groupby(g).diff().mask(mask2)

print (df)
   Time   Data  Time Difference
0     1  Start              NaN
1     2      1              NaN
4     5      R              3.0
6     7  Start              NaN
7     8      3              NaN
8     9      R              1.0
```